# Перенос строки в парсере

Tags: delphi-7, парсер

Можно ли указать перенос строки при парсинге? Пробовал писать в одну строку, также пробовал  #10+#13, но безуспешно. Если можно выполнить этот перенос, то подскажите как, вот строки в которых надо указать перенос:

```
 <div class="wrap_fix">
    <a href="http://news.tut.by/politics/329034.html" data-hint-source="1">
```

Comment: @Толя Guard Попробуйте указать "\r\n" или через мнемонику: 

    &#10;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для Delphi порпобуйте chr(13)+chr(10)

Answer (score 0):

REGEX:

```
|<div class=\"wrap_fix\">\s*<a href=\"http:\/\/news\.tut\.by\/\d+\.html\" data-hint-source=\"\d+\">|gi
```

За пробелы, переносы, табуляции и т.д отвечает: \s* - звёздочка означает что их может не быть или быть сколько угодно.

Я не знаю диалекта Delphi, но если там используются regex типа PCRE, то этот код Вам должен помочь.

Comment: Ругается компилятор на \s*.

Comment: @GenchiK Автор вроде указал, что нужно "указать перенос при парсинге", а не учитывать пробельные символы

Comment: @romeo, в \s попадает и перенос строки.

Comment: @GenchiK Да всё верно "\s" = " \f\n\r\t\v", но вопрос поставлен иначе. Вот и @yalex1 аналогичным образом его протрактовал, как и я.

Comment: Отлично!) Понял )